# Azure rest apis to ListKeys of classic storage account

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-management-api, azure-storage-account

I wanted to retrieve the access keys of classic storage account. 
I found this online

```
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/{accountName}/listKeys?api-version=2016-12-01
```

But this is not applicable for classic storage account.  When I replace the Microsoft.Storage to Microsoft.ClassicStorage, it throws the following error

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidRequestUri",
        "message": "The request uri is invalid. The requested path '/subscriptions/{subscriptionID}/resourceGroups/{myresourcegroup}/providers/Microsoft.ClassicStorage/storageAccounts/{myStorageAccount}/listKeys' is not found."
    }
}
```

NOTE: I am using Application permissions not delegated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For classic storage accounts, the documented way to list keys is using Service Management API (unfortunately I am not able to find the documentation).

You can get the keys for a classic storage accounts using ARM API as well however it is not supported and Microsoft may remove that API completely anytime. To do so, simply use the following URL:

> https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.ClassicStorage/storageAccounts/{accountName}/listKeys?api-version=2015-06-01

It is also recommended that you convert your classic storage accounts to ARM storage accounts if possible.

Comment: Thank you so much! I cannot use method 1, as I am actually attempting to replace service management api's with the azure rest api's because service managements api's wont support application permissions.  With method 2, Still I am getting the same error   - InvalidRequestUri

Comment: Can you please try with any of the following api versions: 2016-11-01, 2016-04-01, 2015-12-01, 2015-06-01, 2014-06-01, 2014-04-01-beta, 2014-04-01, 2014-01-01? I just tried with 2015-06-01 version and I was able to list the keys.

Comment: Its working now!!!!!  it was a postman error, With Advanced rest api client it worked... Thank you so much !! :-)

Comment: Can you help me with this too , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45834981/how-to-get-the-configuration-of-cloudserviceclassic-with-azure-arm-api