# How to get the configuration of CloudService(classic) with Azure ARM API

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-resource-manager

I wanted to get the configuration of CloudService(classic), I did the following

1) Get the Resource ID: Cloudservice->properties->resourceID

```
Resource Id: /subscriptions/{mySubscriptionID}/resourceGroups/{myResourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.ClassicCompute/domainNames/{myCloudServicename}/
```

2) I used this resourceID as follows

https://management.azure.com/**subscriptions/{mySubscriptionID}/resourceGroups/{myResourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.ClassicCompute/domainNames/{myCloudServicename}**/deploymentslots/Production?api-version=2015-06-01

It worked in the first attempt only.

Is this a correct way ?  If No, then please give me a solution

**NOTE:**
I referred this link: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460804.aspx

```
GET https://management.core.windows.net/<subscription-id>/services/hostedservices/<cloudservice-name>/deploymentslots/<deployment-slot>
```

Thanks 
~HARI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this a correct way ? If No, then please give me a solution

I have created a test classic cloud service and use the arm api to get the configuration it work well.

It could be get multiple times.

I guess maybe something wrong with your auth token or api-version.

Here has an easy way to get the configuration.

You could access the [resources explorer](https://resources.azure.com) site created by azure.

In this site, we could directly use the arm api to get the azure resources information(this tool will send arm api to get the information, you could use F12 to check how it send the request).

After login in this site, you could search your cloud service name.

Details you could see this image:

[image]

Comment: Yeah ! Great.. Actually my requirement is,  get the config then edit and upload it back. All via ARM API. I had a difficult time in getting the ARM API... with this explorer I can get the API's with no time.  Its really a great info... Thanks a lot.    :-) :-)

Comment: If you feel my answer is useful. Please mark it as answer for other folk who faced the same error.

Answer (score 0):

With the **Azure resource explorer** I am able to get all the ARM API's(specific to my service) and its required information like the request and response parameters specifically api-version(which is tricky to find) with simple F12.

This is quick and easy solution for my problem. 
Thanks @BrandoZhang for this suggestion.