# Failed to Get Azure Storage Key using Get-AzureStorageKey in Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-storage

I logged in using an application account(service principle) then ran Get-AzureStorageKey -StorageAccountName myclassicStorageAccount 
and got: this error: 
Get-AzureStorageKey : No default subscription has been designated. Use Select-AzureSubscription -Default  to set the default subscription.
but when I run Select-AzureSubscription -Default , it told me this sub doesn't exist, even though this account is owner role for that but.

Please help. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, if you login your account with service principal, you could not use classic Power Shell cmdlet.

You could use Azure Rest API to get storage account access key, you could check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45814332/azure-rest-apis-to-listkeys-of-classic-storage-account). You could use the following power shell.

```
Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceId "/subscriptions/*******/resourceGroups/stlvm/providers/Microsoft.ClassicStorage/storageAccounts/stlsac"  -Action "listKeys" -ApiVersion "2016-11-01" -Force
```

You could get the resource id on Azure Portal.

[image]

I test in my lab, it works for me.

[image]

Update:

You could use `Get-AzureRmResource` to get classic storage account resource group.

```
##`stlsac` is my classic storage account name, replace it
$storage = Get-AzureRmResource | Where {$_.ResourceType -eq "Microsoft.ClassicStorage/storageAccounts" -and $_.ResourceName -eq "stlsac"}

Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceName stlsac -ResourceType Microsoft.ClassicStorage/storageAccounts -ResourceGroupName $storage.ResourceGroupName -Action "listKeys" -ApiVersion "2016-11-01" -Force
```

Comment: If you have a Microsoft account/Azure AD account, of course you could use `Add-AzureAccount` to login and use `Get-AzureStorageKey`.

Comment: Thanks, but to get ResourceId or ResourceGroup name for given storageaccount without loggin to Azure Portal?     both Find-AzureRnResource    and  Find-AzureRmResourceGroup  didn't return anything for classic storage account.

Comment: @lidong Yes, it is possible. You could use `Get-AzureRmrsource` to get it, see my update answer.