# Azure : Get classic storage account key using StorageManagementClient

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage

I am trying to automatically retrieve the key of a classic Storage Account using StorageManagementClient.

For new ones, this worked fine `client.storage_accounts.list_keys(resource_group_name, storage_account_name)` but for classic ones I end up with the following error :

```
msrestazure.azure_exceptions.CloudError: Azure Error: ResourceNotFound
Message: The Resource 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<storage_account_name>' under resource group '<resource_group_name>' was not found.
```

I did not find a way to also include classic resources in the documentation (see https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/azure-mgmt-storage/azure/mgmt/storage).

Do I simply have to use another API / client ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't with this package, you need to use the ASM (Azure Service Management) package called `azure-servicemanagement-legacy` : https://pypi.org/project/azure-servicemanagement-legacy/

See this unittest from this testfile: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/azure-servicemanagement-legacy/tests/test_legacy_mgmt_storage.py

```
def test_get_storage_account_keys(self):
    # Arrange
    self._create_storage_account(self.storage_account_name)

    # Act
    result = self.sms.get_storage_account_keys(self.storage_account_name)

    # Assert
    self.assertIsNotNone(result)
    self.assertIsNotNone(result.url)
    self.assertIsNotNone(result.service_name)
    self.assertIsNotNone(result.storage_service_keys.primary)
    self.assertIsNotNone(result.storage_service_keys.secondary)
    self.assertIsNone(result.storage_service_properties)
```

**Edit**: You might want to try a ARM resource call using `azure-mgmt-resource` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45814624/4074838 for details) to this URL: `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.ClassicStorage/storageAccounts/{accountName}/listKeys?api-version=2015-06-01`

You can create a ResourceManagementClient client `client`, and call `client.resources.get_by_id(subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.ClassicStorage/storageAccounts/{accountName}/listKeys, '2015-06-01')`
As described in the answer I mention however, there is no guarantee this call will continue to work in the future (if it's even still working now)

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure.mgmt.resource.resources.v2017_05_10.operations.resourcesoperations?view=azure-python#get-by-id